# Trying to parse words into a HashMap from an input stream (character by character), however, spaces keep coming in?

Tags: java, tokenize

I'm trying to parse words from an input file into a hashmap where every word maps to the amount of times it occurs in a file. I must do this via a character stream (i.e: I have to traverse the file character by character). Now this is working fine, however, my parser seems to sometimes skip whitespaces and include two words as a single string (e.g: themiddle, helloworld, etc...) can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? Also, is there anyway to include words that are of the form (Letter/Digit).(letter/Digit). (so it is a letter then a dot then a letter for as many times (abbreviations in other words such as I.B.M)).

Here is a snippet of my code

```
    int i; 
            while ((i=f.read()) != -1) {


              if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(i)) {
                  st += (char)i;
              }

              else  {

                  st = st.toLowerCase();

                  if (tokens.containsKey(st)) {
                      int temp = tokens.get(st);
                      tokens.put(st, temp+=1);
                  }
                  else {

                      tokens.put(st, 1);
                      st = "";
                  }

              }
          }

            tokens.remove("");
    return tokens;

}`
```

any help would be appreciated, the input is a filereader object btw.

Answer (score 0):

This is what sets your string back to empty:

```
st = "";
```

So it should be in the outer `else`, not inner, otherwise you're only setting it as empty when you find a new (not repeated) word. This will make the next word concatenate with the previous.

As for the second part, you could do something like

```
if ( Character.isLetterOrDigit(i) || (st != "" && (char)i == '.') ) {
    st += (char)i;
}
```

**Edit:**

And then, to remove the last period, just check if the last character of `st` is a period when it gets to the `else`.

**Another edit:**

If you want exactly one letter before each period, you can check the string `st` backwards in the `if`. Or just process it after the split, in the `else`. Or even use [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

How you implement this is up to you.

Comment: Ah this is great! Thanks a ton. The only thing with your suggestion below, is that it'll capture the dots after words too, which I don't want, I only want the abbreviation sequence. For instance: if there's something like hello. or I.B.M. it'll take the whole thing, what I want is just hello, or just I.B.M if that makes sense? The only problem is I can't really check for after the character

Comment: @skidjoe Edited it.

Comment: Sorry for the incessant stream of questions, is there any way to do this without using substring methods, just only using primitives? That's essentially what I'm trying to do. I'm not aware of any character method to do this

Comment: You can keep track of the last read character, and a counter of how many letter/digit characters in a row were read. Then with these two pieces of information, you can decide if you add the period to the string or if you tokenize it.

You will still have to remove the last period manually, though, since you can't read ahead of your character stream.